# Mouse locator beacon

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Looking for information on using a mouse locator beacon that would signal to a user where the mouse is currently located on a form?

An example of this the the Search functionality in the Options screen of Toad. If I select a search result item from the list, the correct panel is displayed, the mouse is moved to the middle of the control and a locator beacon of 3 rings is displayed.

Another example would be the old Delphi version of CodeRush from Mark Miller. When you dropped a marker in the code and hit the ESC key, the editor would take you back to the marker and indicate where your editor's cursor position was with a locator beacon.

Click [here](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx) for a visual example from CodeRush under the Collect Marker title. That is about 2/3 of the way through the beacon shrinking.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: See this example how to use the `OnMouseMove` event, [`OnMouseMove`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/OnMouseMove_(Delphi)).

Comment: @LURD, Not looking for OnMouseMove, I know how that works. Looking for functionality to notify enduser of where the mouse is on a form after the application moves it to a control. The old CodeRush used locator beacons when picking up markers and Toad uses a mouse locator beacon in it's Options Search functionality.

Comment: @LURD, it's badly described, but what OP actually wants is to move the cursor to the center of a control and flash that control three times. That's what Toad does (except moving the cursor in version I have). So you can just extend the code of your cursor mover. It's the effect shown in the project from my [`SO project trunk root`](https://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed). Of course that project is horrible (and I bet buggy as well :-) since all this stuff can be nicely wrapped into a class. But I've no time for doing so.

Comment: @TLama, You are almost correct, but I don't want to flash the control. I was a locator beacon ((( ))) that is a set of circles shrinking down at the mouse cursor position.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I've been confused because my Toad 11.5 doesn't even move the cursor. It only flashes the controls. Well, rather try describe it with words than telling what application shows the effect.

Comment: Please reopen this question. It is not off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen what Toad does, and I'm certain that you'll find the below visually not pleasing. It may give you some ideas anyway. Requires a panel and a timer.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FRingCount: Integer;
    FRingRect: TRect;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  Pt := Point(Panel1.Width div 2, Panel1.Height div 2);
  MapWindowPoints(Panel1.Handle, HWND_DESKTOP, Pt, 1);
  SetCursorPos(Pt.X, Pt.Y);

  Timer1.Interval := 100;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
  FRingCount := 0;
  FRingRect := Rect(Pt.X - 20, Pt.Y - 20, Pt.X + 20, Pt.Y + 20);
  OffsetRect(FRingRect, -Left, -Top);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  DC: HDC;
begin
  DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
  try
    Canvas.Handle := DC;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNotXor;
    Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;

    if FRingCount > 0 then begin
      Canvas.Ellipse(FRingRect);     // remove previous ellipse
      InflateRect(FRingRect, -3, -3);
    end;

    if FRingCount > 5 then
      Timer1.Enabled := False
    else
      Canvas.Ellipse(FRingRect);

    Canvas.Handle := 0;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
  end;
  Inc(FRingCount);
end;
```